# How to generate serial number by level for hierachy data in sqlite?

Tags: database, sqlite, hierarchy, data-cleaning

I am working on a hierarchy data, product BOM specifically. One of the jobs is to add serial number for each part depending on its (and its ancestors') level in the BOM. You can see an example as in the table below:

[Level -> Serial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGRWE.png)

I did it with python pandas, with MS Excel, and now need to do it with sqlite. Tried with the recursive CTE, but no clue. Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a way of tracking what rows have what other row as a parent, and overall order, it's pretty easy to do with a recursive CTE. Consider this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE sample(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, parent INTEGER REFERENCES sample(id));
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (1,NULL), (2,1), (3,2), (4,1), (5,4);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (6,5), (7,1), (8,7), (9,8), (10,8), (11,7);
```

where the `id` primary key determines the order rows should be displayed in, and is referenced by the `parent` column to tell which row is which's parent. A `null` parent is the root.

and then this query to build the `serial` paths like in your image:

```
WITH
  ranks AS
   (SELECT id, parent, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY parent ORDER BY id) AS rn FROM sample)
, paths AS (SELECT id, parent, 0 as level, '' AS serial
            FROM ranks WHERE parent IS NULL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT c.id, c.parent, p.level + 1, p.serial || '.' || c.rn
            FROM ranks AS c
            JOIN paths AS p ON c.parent = p.id)
SELECT id, level, substr(serial, 2) as serial
FROM paths
ORDER BY id;
```

which produces:

```
id          level       serial
----------  ----------  ----------
1           0
2           1           1
3           2           1.1
4           1           2
5           2           2.1
6           3           2.1.1
7           1           3
8           2           3.1
9           3           3.1.1
10          3           3.1.2
11          2           3.2
```

It has to use two CTEs, one normal, one recursive, because Sqlite doesn't let you use window functions in a recursive query (Speaking of window functions, this query needs Sqlite 3.25 or newer to use `row_number()`). The `ranks` CTE generates the numbers used in the path based on ranking all rows with the same parent, and the `paths` one builds the `serial` path values and computes the level from the root.

Comment: Thank you! It is more complicated than I exptected, but it works like a charm!